# Iteration of array in Liquid

Tags: loops, frontend, liquid, templating

I'm using an analog of Shopify and I'm stuck with syntax of Liquid.

I need to output in the template the field with an id `product[product_field_values_attributes][][value]`

So I need to write a loop to get the `i` value of this array.
I'm confused with this empty element in the brackets.

I've looked through the examples of loop syntax in Liquid but all of those arrays are simple and they are not my case.

For example, the `Title` field has id `product[title]` and in Liquid template i call this variable `product.title` and it works fine.

But all my tries to write a loop for this array failed.

Please, help to write a loop to get the values of the array stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting the array directly onto the page using `{{ product }}` or `{{ product[product_field_values_attributes] }}` somewhere in the HTML. That will do a JSON-like string representation of the array. From there you can figure out what the keys for the array are.

I'm not sure what you're saying about the `i` value. You don't reference `i` anywhere else in your question. If you can clarify that then we can see if something can be done about it.